# Number of all possible orientations in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, orientation

What is the number of all possible orientations for an undirected graph? I think it must be $2^{|E|}$, because we have $|E|$ edges, each of them can have 2 choices for it's direction. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Do we have to worry about duplicates under isomorphism?

Suppose we have a graph with two vertices $a$ and $b$ and a single edge. There are two ways to orient the edge, so we have two graphs $\{a \rightarrow b\}$ or $\{a \leftarrow b\}$. Do we count this as two distinct graphs, or do we count this as one graph because they are isomorphic?

Comment: @Mike Pierce, in this case we don't worry about it, because our nodes have fixed labels and we can't change labels. In the other hand this is important whether a label is source or target. But what is the answer if we are worry about duplicates under isomorphism? Is there any practical solution?

Comment: I think that if we were to worry about duplicates under isomorphism, this problem becomes *much* harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming that you don't have any loops (edges that have the same source and target).  Depending on your definition of *graph*, these might be excluded already.  The number of orientations is $2^n$, where $n$ is the number of non-loop edges.

Comment: If we have also $m$ loop edges, we must add number of such edges to your answer ($2^n+m$). Is it true?

Comment: Each edge with distinct source and target (non-loop) has two possible orientations and each loop has just one possible orientation, so the number of possible orientations is $$(\underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdots 2}_{n}) \cdot (\underbrace{1 \cdot 1 \cdots 1}_{m}) = 2^n.$$